# How can i write bits to a file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a table that looks like this:

> '00'
>
> '010'
>
> '011'
>
> '100'
>
> '1010'
>
> '1011'
>
> '1100'
>
> '11010'
>
> '11011'
>
> '11100'
>
> '11101'
>
> '11110'
>
> '11111'

This is a cell array that contains the binary codification of some characters(based on Shannon-Fano algorithm.
My question is how do i write this codes to file so that every 0 and 1 are interpreted as a bit.

Is something as `fwrite(F,V{I,3},'bit1')` going to work ( the binary codification being on the third column and using I to identify the row) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, file operations are inherently byte-oriented.  You may not write partial bytes out.  You need to concatenate all the bits into a string of bytes, and write that string out.  The code might look something like this:

```
allbits = cat(2, V{:,3});   % concatenate all bits into one giant binary string
npadding = 8 - mod(length(allbits), 8); % number of bits needed to produce an even multiple of 8
if(npadding < 8)   % pad with zeros
    allbits = [allbits repmat('0', 1, npadding)];
end
bytestring = reshape(allbits, 8, []).';  % reshape into a matrix of binary strings
bytes = bin2dec(bytestring);  % convert to integers
fwrite(fid, bytes, 'uint8');   % be sure to write out the integers as 8-bit bytes
```

This code makes some assumptions, which you'll want to adjust to your expectations: order of bits in the file, type of padding for incomplete bytes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i have managed to implement what you said and is working, but i have a problem when i concatenate a big number of codes.It takes very much time to construct a full string.
Do you know how can i make the concatenate operation take less time?

Comment: What might help is to not actually store the bit strings (even in the cell array).  It's an inefficient representation.  Instead, store an integer containing the bits you want, and another integer with the number of valid bits.  Then the concatentation operation involves bitshift and bitwise or.  It's tricky to get this correct, so try to find a local C programmer for assistance.